# awk for-in loop giving unexpected output?

Tags: for-loop, awk, for-in-loop

I am currently writing an `awk` script within a bash script. One of my arguments needs to be split and cycled through. Eg: for an argument of `1234` I need to cycle through each number in the order written. So, `2413` is not equivalent.

I used `split` to create an array and then a `for-in` loop to cycle through the array. I assumed it would cycle through in order, but it is not.

My code is as follows:

```
split(cols,toShow,"")
for (c in toShow)
    printf "%s\n",c
```

`cols` is passed to the `awk` command using the `-v` option and gives the following output:

```
4
1
2
3
```

After testing this a few times, with varying lengths of arguments and using both numbers and letters, it appears that the `for` loop starts at element 4 of the array, cycles through to the end in order, then cycles through elements 1 to 3, instead of the expected starting at element 1 and cycling to the end.

Is there anyway to change the behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT** For clarification, I am using `gawk` in xubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arrays in awk aren't (necessarily) stored in the order from the original source.

Also, using numbers as your input is confusing the issue

Here is a solution that will illustrate the problem

```
awk 'END{cols="ABCD";n=split(cols,toShow,"")
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    printf "%s\n",toShow[i] }' /dev/null
```

** output**

```
A
B
C
D
```

To see what I mean, edit your code to ABCD and you'll still the your numeric output as `for c in toShow` is printing the keys and not the values of the assoc array.

If you edit ABCD in my sample, to 1234, you'll get the output you're looking for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The fact it was outputting the index didn't really matter as it still showed it wasn't outputting in the right order, however changing to the longer-form `for` loop fixed the problem so thank you :)